# How to assign hotkeys to paragraph styles in Pages 5?

Tags: pages, iwork, text, shortcut-menu

Pages '09 had the paragraph styles drawer with a list of all styles. Each style had the following context menu:

[image: Pages 09 paragraph styles context menu]

On the new Pages 5, this is how that context menu looks however.

[image: Pages 5 paragraph styles context menu]

Noticeably missing is the option to assign a hotkey to a paragraph style. Is anyone aware of a way to do this in the new Pages 5?

Comment: Looks like I asked the same thing with different wording here: (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107782/is-it-possible-to-assign-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-to-styles-in-pages-5-0?noredirect=1#comment126406_107782). Let's see if any of them gets answered. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature was lost in the initial release of Pages 5, but was brought back in in iWork 5.2.

You can choose the shortcuts F1 through F8, and it appears to be a per-document setting. I suspect the reason it has to be per-document is that the styles themselves are part of the document. You may also be able to apply shortcuts to a template, so that new documents based on it get the shortcuts, if you use the same templates/styles a lot.

**The UI in Pages 5.2.2:**

[image: Pages 5.2.2 setting keyboard shortcuts for styles]

I'm not entirely sure why, but Apple have done similar things in a few of their applications, with major updates (e.g. 4.x to 5.x) seeing a bunch of features disappear with a simplified UI, and then some of the lost features come back in minor subsequent updates.