# Is it possible to assign custom Keyboard Shortcuts to Styles in Pages 5.0?

Tags: keyboard, pages

In the previous Pages release there used to be the possibility to assign keyboard shortcuts to styles, although limited to the F1..F8 keys.

Apparently this feature is missing from the freshly installed Pages 5.0. Even worse, shortcuts do not apply to documents created with a template that defined the shortcuts link.

Is there any other way to assign keyboard shortcut to styles?

Cheers

====

Update: in current version (5.2) of Pages the feature has been re-introduced. I guess this closes the question.

Comment: A similar question from last week: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106711/how-to-assign-hotkeys-to-paragraph-styles-in-pages-5

Comment: I swear I did some search before posting mine! :-) But I was looking for Shortcuts, not for Hotkeys. But ...yes, the question is basically the same. Thanks for linking them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current version (5.2) of Pages the feature has been re-introduced. I guess this closes the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no way to do it. Apple apparently removed the feature and it is also not possible to do it via the OS X shortcuts because there is no Menu entry for choosing styles in Pages.

Here's a discussion in the Apple Support Communities where people are pretty upset about this truly annoying feature regression: https://discussions.apple.com/message/23628178#23628178